# Buttons added dynamically to form don’t appear

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm trying to create 4 buttons on my form when I click on `button1`, but the buttons don’t show up. Why not?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button[] b = new Button[4];
   for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      b[i] = new Button();
      b[i].Name = "button" + i;
      b[i].Location = new Point(43, 39 + 10 * i);
      b[i].Size = new Size(158, 48);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  What is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only created them, but you also need to add them to your form with: `this.Controls.Add(b[i]);`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button[] b = new Button[4];
   for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
   {
       b[i] = new Button();
       b[i].Name = "button" + i;
       b[i].Location = new Point(43, 39 + 10 * i);
       b[i].Size = new Size(158, 48);

       this.Controls.Add(b[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Buttons are not apearing on the form.

Comment: @Shaharyar what do you have on your Page_Load ?

Comment: @Shaharyar as it was accepted I assume that you've managed to make it work. Good

Comment: @2GDev I am sorry , i was doing something wrong. Its a perfect solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

All you do is create an array of buttons, and assign buttons at indices. Your form knows nothing of these buttons, they could be an array of integers or anything for all that matters at this point. You will need to put them in the form's container:

```
Controls.Add(b[i]);
```

Now your form will take ownership of them, managing disposal when the container is disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace winFormButtons
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button[] b = new Button[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                b[i] = new Button();
                b[i].Name = "button" + i;
                b[i].Location = new Point(43, 39 + 10 * i);
                b[i].Size = new Size(158, 48);    
                b[i].Click += new EventHandler(OnClick);
                this.Controls.Add(b[i]);
            }
        }

        public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            MessageBox.Show("Hello Handler:" + ((Button)sender).Name);    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Panel` on your form. and add this line in your code

```
panel1.Controls.Add(b[i])
```